# The html page does not display video list

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, append

I'm loading a list of videos from the database into an html page, as per the script below. But the videos are not displayed. I tested part of the script separately, and it works, I think the problem is in the .append(). Could someone suggest me a solution. Grateful

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://vjs.zencdn.net/7.20.3/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://vjs.zencdn.net/7.20.3/video.min.js"></script>
</head>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
   $.getJSON("today.php", function(dados1) {
        
     tr = $('<tr/>');                               
     $('#tbl_post tbody tr').remove();
     $('#tbl_post').append(tr);                             
                        
     Object.keys(dados1).forEach(function (i) {     
        
        tr = $('<tr/>');
        tr.append("<video id='my-video' class='video-js' controls preload='auto' width='340' height='264' >");
        tr.append("<source src='" + dados1[i].video + "' type='video/mp4'>");
        tr.append("</video>");          
    $('#tbl_post').append(tr);
                
      });
   });
});
</script>

<body>
   <table id="tbl_post" border="0" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"> </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The only valid children of a `tr` are `td` or `th`. `video` is not. Also, `table` elements should only be used for tabular data, not lists. Use `ul` for unordered lists and `ol` for ordered lists.

Comment: What is the content of `dados1[i].video` ?

Comment: on top of what was already said above, you should use a multi-line string by using either linebreak with a slash or using backticks instead of using 3 append functions when 1 would be sufficient. Also, you should append the `source` to the video tag, not the table-row.

Comment: İsmail Can Karataş dados1[i].video contain the url of the video

Comment: ** CORRETION - I rewrote it like this and it worked                                                                                         var path = 'https://andchir.github.io/jquery-video-extend/video/Sintel.mp4";
       
tr.append("<video id='my-video' class='video-js' controls preload='auto' width='340' height='264' > <source src='"+path+"' type='video/mp4'> </video>");